# Bash - "timeout" with tail issue

Tags: bash, grep, tail, timeout

```
timeout 0.6s $(tail -f ./file.txt | grep -qA2 --line-buffered "detail: " | grep -E -- "$KeyNumbers")
```

So timeout isn't functioning as intended with this. I want it to cancel if tail has no match after 0.6s, and continue if a match is found but timeout to have an exit status... but instead it currently only continues past this point if the $(tail...) section finds a match.

No exit code is found either with echo $?, it's as if timeout just can't control it?

I also tried it without enclosing tail with $( ), worse result.
What am I missing here? Is there a better solution?

**Solution:**

Thanks `@lukemassa` for the help. Working result is:

```
timeout 0.6s tail -f ./file.txt | grep -qA2 --line-buffered -E -- "detail: $KeyNumbers"
```

Their post explains it, and in the comments was question of the point of the 2nd grep command if the 1st one is -q (which suppresses output essentially) which made me realize I didn't combine them like I had previously in my script for other elements.

Comment: So, okay, you want to end the pipeline if no match is found in 0.6 s, that's clear. But what if there _is_ a match? Should the pipeline then be left live for longer? For another 0.6 s after each match? Indefinitely?

Comment: Yeah if no match is found in 0.6s, it should end, if a match is found it should also end, but ultimately the difference I'm looking for is timeout to output to $? a different number if that fails/succeeds, lukemassa's answer works but doesn't output a different number.

Comment: hmm. `-q` and `-A2` probably don't mean much together. `-A2` means to print two lines following the match too, but `-q` inhibits printing any output. Just `grep -q` would do if what you're looking is on a single line. Also `--line-buffered` is probably unnecessary there, since it, too should only affect the output. But the first version looks like you'd have `detail:` on line, and the keynumber then on one of the following two lines, and that would be a different case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in `$()` is evaluated by the shell, so becomes

```
timeout 0.6s "stuff from the file"
```

which will then try to execute and fail.

Have you tried:

```
timeout 0.6s tail -f ./file.txt | grep -qA2 --line-buffered "detail: " | grep -E -- "$KeyNumbers"
```

Comment: Well that solved part of it, thanks. Just need to get an exit code from timeout now. Seems to currently output 1 to $? if timeout beats tail or vice versa.

Comment: @Kai Seems like you have solved the exit-status issue too.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; `tail -f` is going to continue indefinitely, so regardless of whether you get output or not, timeout is stopping the command. Also I'm confused about the `-q` in the second command, that suppresses all output so what's the point of the third command?

Comment: tail seems to exit though when grep finds a match with the -q option i.e `tail -f ./file.txt | grep -q` due to the file being truncated I believe. I don't think the script would even work if it didn't exit.

Good point about the -q thing though, I had forgotten to change it to be all in one like this `grep -qA2 --line-buffered -E -- "detail: $KeyNumbers"`

Comment: Ah I see. I think your issue then is the exit code of `timeout` is propagating through. You can try turning off pipefail or maybe something wonky like `(timeout 0.6s tail -f ./file.txt || true) | grep ...`. Either way, I'm still skeptical the third command is doing anything given that `-q` means the second command has no output

Comment: Hopefully this isn't a spoken-too-soon moment but it works, fixing the stupid mistake of the 2nd grep command and putting it with the first one as it should have been (the other tail listener things are combined). But yeah, now it outputs a 0 and 1, depending on which fails first. 

So basically. Key pressed = 0, key held however is 1. Brilliant stuff. Thanks for the slight nudge with the 2nd grep part!

End result: `timeout 0.6s tail -f ./file.txt | grep -qA2 --line-buffered -E -- "detail: $KeyNumbers"`